# Why is the internal energy proportional to the number of particles

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I'm considering about the stability and fluctuations of the canonical ensemble. By Taylor expansion of the entropy of the system, I find

$S_{tot}=S(U,V,N)+S(U_{tot},V_{tot}-V,N_{tot}-N)-U \left.\frac{\partial S(U_{tot})}{\partial U_{tot}}\right|_{V,N}+\frac{U^2}{2}\left.\frac{\partial^2S(U_{tot})}{\partial U_{tot}^2}\right|_{V,N}+o(U^3)$

In the notes I am following, without explanation, it follows

$S_{tot}=S(U,V,N)-\frac{U}{T_0}+const$

$S_{tot}=\frac{1}{T_0}(U-T_0 S)=-\frac{-F}{T_0}$

This is explained by stating that $U\propto N$. Why is this the case, and how does it explain the entropy of the canonical ensemble?

Comment: Hint: Consider the equipartition assumption and the relation of $N$ to the degrees of freedom.